# How can I kill nodemon process after running mocha tests?

Tags: node.js, gulp, mocha.js, nodemon

I need to have a `gulp` task that starts the server, runs `mocha` tests against it and finally closes it. I have the following code:

```
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var nodemon = require('nodemon');

gulp.task('my-integration-tests', function () {    
  return nodemon({ script: './server.js' })
    .on('start', function () {
      gulp.src(['./mySpecs.spec.js'])
        .pipe(mocha());            
  });    
});
```

The server is successfully started and the tests are run. However after this the process created by `nodemon` is still alive. Is there a way to instruct `nodemon` to close upon completion? Also having the application opening and closing in the same process as the `mocha` tests is not an option with the current configuration.

---

UPDATE:

Apart from ThomasBromans answer, I came up with this solution which seems to work in my case. Whenever `gulp-mocha` finishes the tests it will kind of emit an 'end' event. When this happens we only need to emit 'quit' on the child process then kill the main process, like so:

```
gulp.task('my-integration-tests', function () {    
  var childProc = nodemon({ script: './server.js' });

  childProc.on('quit', function () {
    console.log('event emitted, child process is being killed');
  })

  childProc.on('start', function () {
      gulp.src(['./mySpecs.spec.js'])
        .pipe(mocha())
        .once('end', function () {
          console.log('mocha stuff ended. time to kill processes');
          childProc.emit('quit');
          setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('kill main process');
            process.exit();
          }, 1500);
        });            
  });    
});
```

Unfortunately I still need the timeout between the child process being killed and the killing of the main process, if I remove the timeout it happens that the child process remains hanging. This solution is of course open to improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You can exit the process with `process.exit()`. Just add another *.pipe*. Your task will look like this:

```
gulp.task('my-integration-tests', function () {    
  return nodemon({ script: './server.js' })
    .on('start', function () {
      gulp.src(['./mySpecs.spec.js'])
        .pipe(mocha())
        .pipe(process.exit());
  });
});
```

**EDIT** running tasks in a sequence (I am not sure this works without any changes):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    mocha = require('gulp-mocha'),
    nodemon = require('nodemon'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('nodemon', function() {
    return nodemon({script: './server.js'});
});

gulp.task('mocha', function() {
    return mocha();
});

gulp.task('stop', function() {
    process.exit();
});

gulp.task('my-integration-tests', function () {    
    runSequence('nodemon',
                'mocha',
                'stop');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This just kills my process outright. It seems mocha doesn't even have time to start properly as the pipe command arrives at process.exit(). It also kills the gulp task process, but the process created by nodemon is alive and well as seen in the task manager.

I'm currently looking at "nodemon.emit('quit');" type of commands, taken from their official api, will see if I can get it to emit at the end of the mocha run.

Comment: @Vee6 Hmm. Weird. I have not tried it with Mocha but it worked seamlessly with some other gulp tasks. You can try running a sequence. I can update my answer if you want to?

Comment: by sequence you mean something like async.series or something like it? if you could update for this case I would be grateful.

Comment: @Vee6 I have updated my answer. Not 100% sure about the syntax though. You might need to update some minor things.

Comment: Thanks. The runSequence solution looks pretty elegant. I cam up with my own in the meantime which I will also post.